# How to solve Symfony 4 Password null error?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a form which has a Repeat password. On blank submission, I get the following error.

```
Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "password".
```

UserType:

```
    $builder
        ->add('email',TextType::class)
        ->add('password',RepeatedType::class,  
              [
            'type'=>PasswordType::class,
            'required'=> false,      
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'empty_data'=> ''
        ])
        ->add('firstname',TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname',TextType::class)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ;
```

When I insert the value in either password field I get the validation message, but if I keep both blanks I get the above-written error.

Comment: What line and script is the error message coming from? Are you using type hinting in your User entity `setPassword` function?

Comment: No, I don't have any such things and it doesn't show the error line.

Comment: Check your log files, it will have this information.

Comment: Yous should use Assert
https://github.com/symfony/demo/issues/741

Comment: @hous Thanks the link you given solved the issue.. :)